# Are there any other German nouns besides 'Joghurt' that can be any gender?

Tags: article

This is what Duden says about Joghurt:

> Joghurt, Jogurt, der, die oder das

Dict.cc provides some more detail:

> der/[bes. österr., schweiz., südd. auch] das/[bes. ostösterr. auch] die Joghurt

Comment: Well, stick a tail on me and call me a weasel. I never knew **die** Joghurt would be acceptable and **der** Joghurt I thought was just a peculiarity of us Southern Germanics. Die Joghurt sounds bizarre to my ears.

Comment: _Die Joghurt_ sounds like broken Ruhrpott slang. "Ey Schakkeline, schmeiß mich mal die Joghurt rübä."

Comment: In an ancient German textbook, a poem was reprinted containing the line "O seelenloses Automat!", with a footnote claiming that the neutral inflection was obsolete and the current usage was feminine. By the time I got hold of it, that was obsolete as well, and today it's masculine.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu Wie vom seligen Tegtmeir selber! ;)

Comment: Are you looking for nouns with the same meaning or nouns with different meanings depending on gender are acceptable too?

Comment: @Alex.S Same meaning

Comment: @Eller So `[kuː]` does not count. Otherwise I would say: der Coup, die Kuh, das Q.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/die-verteilung-der-artikel-genusangabe-im-rechtschreibduden) gibt es unter 20. Er listet, inklusive Joghurt auf:

> - der, die oder das Bookmark
> - der, die oder das Joghurt
> - der, die oder das Triangel

Answer (score 1):

Also die / der / das [Nutella](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Nutella). Moreover

> Wie bei Markennamen üblich, hat auch das Wort Nutella kein festgelegtes Geschlecht. Die häufigste anzutreffende Form ist allerdings je nach Region das weibliche oder das sächliche Geschlecht, am seltensten wird der Nutella benutzt.

That explanation is based actually on [Duden](http://www.duden.de/aktuelle_meldungen/alles-gute-zum-geburtstag-), which moreover states:

> Häufig wird die weibliche Form die Nutella verwendet, wohl abgeleitet von der aus dem Italienischen stammenden femininen Endung -ella. Es tritt aber auch die sächliche Form das Nutella auf. Das Neutrum wird häufig auch bei Fremdwörtern gewählt, wenn es keine starken Gründe für das Maskulinum oder das Femininum gibt (...)